# +animateWithDuration:animations:completion: crashes under simulator

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uiview, core-animation

### Update

I too am experiencing the same issue, calls to `+animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` work fine on the device but crash on the simulator.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{
                     NSLog(@"Begin");
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"End");
                 }];
```

As you can see I am not accessing any other objects and it will still crash with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.

### Update 2

It seems to only crash if you pass a `block` in `completion:` passing NULL works fine.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{
                     NSLog(@"Begin");
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

### Original Question

I've been using the phone for development mostly because I was using a library that was not compiled for Intel but have now switched back to the simulator to speed things up.

I'm getting consistient crashes when I use UIView animateWithDuration and have had to comment them out temporarily in my code. They work fine on the phone. I'm on the latest SDK 4.3.1 (almost) and compiling for 4.0 onwards.

Any ideas why this is crashing?

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
    mapTableOverlay.alpha = 0.8;} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the line above is called. Thanks for help....

Comment: I see that you have already included the completion block as well.. but instead of having it empty, could you put just for testing an NSlog statement and see if it crashes?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I am experiencing the exact same issue but didn't realise it was in the simulator only at first.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue :/ Any new idea about this one ? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly an answer, though it does outline what caused the problem, & what might alleviate it - I had exactly the same problem, all of a sudden any UIView animateWithDuration would crash, even if no objects were passed and even without the block on completion. It started when I added the Urban Airship libraries & associated frameworks (libUAirship-1.1.0.a, FNetwork.framework, MobileCoreServices.framework, Security.framework, SystemConfiguration.framework, libz.dylib, libsqlite3.dylib, CoreTelephony.framework, StoreKit.framework) and promptly stopped when I got rid of them again. I know it's nothing to do with the sqlite lib & the storeKit framework cos I'm using them now, but I never tracked it down properly. I'd be grateful for a more thorough answer too!

Comment: It seems to be linked with Urban Airship library. I've since removed this library as I don't need it in current version. The problem has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see more code to be sure but the only object you are accessing is `mapTableOverlay` so seems like the problem has to be with that object. Look at the state when this animation is called. Is it possible that `mapTableOverlay` is being release w/o the iVar being set to nil (perhaps in `viewDidUnload`)?

Adding the following to your question would be helpful:

1. Code wrt the `mapTableOverlay` life cycle
2. Code showing the context of the animation
3. The stack trace from the crash